# How can I subtract an array of strings from another array of strings?

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, subtraction

Okay say I have a DataFrame called joinedarrays that contains 3 columns, and 2 of them are arrays. 
I have an array of strings in those 2 and I want to make a difference between the two array types. Here is some sample output that will make this make more sense.

```
 col1                                   col2                       diffcol
 ['Jack', 'Bill', 'George', 'Rose']     ['Jack', 'Rose', 'Robert']  ['Bill', 'George', 'Robert]
```

I created a udf like so

```
@udf (ArrayType(StringType()))

def udfsetdifference (l1, l2) : 
   return l1 - l2
```

I used this one the two cols and then tried to add it to the DataFrame I already had. Like so:

```
diff = udfsetdifference(joinedarrays.col1, joinedarrays.col2)
```

I'm getting the following error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

when I try to add this difference column to the DataFrame like so

```
joinedarrays = joinedarrays.withColumn('diff', diff)
```

I'm a little new to array subtraction so hopefully, I explained everything accurately.

Here is what show does (although this isn't the same Data I gave previously, I was trying for a more generic example and apply it specifically to this data).

```
+--------------------+----+--------------------+----+
|        collect_list|year|     receivedontsend|diff|
+--------------------+----+--------------------+----+
|[Egypt, Equatoria...|2010|[Romania, Ireland...|null|
|[Egypt, Costa Ric...|2011|[Saint Martin, Gu...|null|
|[Egypt, Costa Ric...|2012|[Croatia, Ireland...|null|
|[Egypt, Equatoria...|2013|[Romania, Croatia...|null|
|[Egypt, Costa Ric...|2014|[Saint Martin, Ro...|null|
|[Egypt, Costa Ric...|2015|[Romania, Croatia...|null|
+--------------------+----+--------------------+----+
```

Comment: yes, sorry it's Spark, let me edit my question one sec.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question with tag *Scala*, but your *UDF* is written in *Python*, so I guess your mixing thing up.

*Spark* is an engine for processing data. It's written in programing language called *Scala*, but it has also API for other languages, like *Python*.

Spark Scala API has a little bit different syntax from Pythons. You'd define your *UDF* like:

```
def udfsetdifference = udf { (l1: Seq[String], l2: Seq[String]) => l1.diff(l2) ++ l2.diff(l1) }
```

Then you can call it like:

```
df.withColumn("diffcol", udfsetdifference('col1, 'col2))
```

If you want to get an answer in Python, then retag your question and remove *Scala* tag and add *Python* and *pyspark* tags.

---

Your error indicates, that you're trying to use `-` operator on lists, which is not supported in *Python*. Correct *UDF* would look like:

```
@udf (ArrayType(StringType()))

def udfsetdifference (l1, l2) : 
   return list(set(l1) ^ set(l2))
```

Comment: Oh that was my bad, I'm doing all my stuff on databricks so I was thinking it was scala, but I now understand what's going on, so yeah Python is probably what I need. I'll re-edit this.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not getting an error anymore, but I'm getting nulls for the difference column now. Is it because I have used collect.list() for each of the columns I'm trying to subtract on? Should I make those sets too?

Comment: And I'm confused on why you are using ^ instead of -, sorry for all the questions!

Comment: @Alex `^` is [symmetric difference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference). Perhaps the answerer thought you might find it more useful.

Comment: Oh perfect, now I'll just investigate why I'm getting nulls

Comment: @Alex with regular diff '-', you wouldn't get the result you described. It's hard to tell why are you getting null. Can you show your shole dataset using `show` function?

Comment: this is the example, I tried to give a generic example above, and apply it to my actual problem, but heres my actual DataFrame which I edited in my initial question.